# Applying for loop to list of dataframes and calculate tables for each data frame in the list

Tags: r, list, csv, for-loop

This question might seem rudimentary, but I am an absolute R beginner and do not get to any solution.

From an experiment, I have large data files from 30 subjects containing exact picture names and the corresponding reaction times. The 140 pictures belong to 9 different categories.

I read all CSV-Files from the given directory in:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

This works fine. Next, I need to duplicate the variable "Code" in each list to not lose the original information.

```
lapply(mylist, transform, category=Code)
```

This works, but the column "category" is just added in my list, not for the separate data frames.

Next, I need to change the variable category into a character, then apply a for-loop and then convert them back to factors.
The for-loop works fine for separate data frames, but how can I make it work for each data frame in the list?? (Here, I have the example for data frame Pb20_2)

```
    for (i in 1:length(Pb20_2$category)){
  if (grepl("NonSocialNegative", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "1"
  if (grepl("NonSocialNeutral", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "2"
  if (grepl("NonSocialPositive", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "3"
}

for (i in 1:length(Pb20_2$category)){
  if (grepl("SocialNegative", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "4"
  if (grepl("SocialNeutral", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "5"
  if (grepl("SocialPositive", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "6"
  if (grepl("F_Face", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "7"
  if (grepl("N_Face", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "8"
  if (grepl("H_Face", Pb20_2$category[i])) Pb20_2$category[i] <- "9"
}
```

After the factor conversion, I need to calculate the absolute number of hits per category

```
Absolute=table(Pb20_2$category,Pb20_2$Type)
```

- which again works fine for a single data frame -

and then the relative number.

```
prop.table(Absolute,1)
```

- which also works fine for a single data frame.

Then, both should be included in one data frame.

I also need the mean reaction time for each category.

```
try=tapply(Pb20_2$RT, Pb20_2$category, mean, na.rm=T )
```

- This again works fine for a single data frame.

In the end, I would like to have all subjects in one data frame, with a variable "ID" sorting it and then 18 columns: each category having two columns, one for the mean reaction time and one for the relative number of hits.

I can calculate this separately for each subject and then in the end bring it together to one data frame - and I already succeeded doing in that - but it takes a lot of time and for the further experiment, I would prefer an easy solution.

I would be really happy to get at least some answers or solutions to parts of my question - thank you for your help!

Best,

Sarah

Comment: Would be very helpful to see some data. Also you snippets are not too complete as `tapply()` and `table()` do not return values easily amenable to a dataframe. If you can, please show full operations on one dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to aggregate the calculations for the separate csv files is to create an empty data frame prior to entering the loop (assign it to a variable). As you loop through making calculations either `cbind` or `rbind` the prop.table to the dataframe to stack the results as needed. You may need to sort data or use keys to merge the data instead of binding it.

If you are trying to sort things from various files and they have different dimension this could be tough. In that case I would bring all the csv's in at once to a huge carefully structured data frame or two and write a straight forward method for sorting and aggregating from there as you need before writing the final file.

It will take longer to write the code if you pull it all in, but it will be easier to see what is happening and more reusable.And it will likely run just as fast as a loop.